# Extracting Specific Regex result from string

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am attempting to extract a part number from a string. I am going to iterate over items, and need to extract the item if it is over 4 characters long, and contains AT LEAST 1 number. It does not have to include letters, but can.

For instance:

```
Line1: 'There is some random information here'
Line2: 'This includes item p23344dd5 as well as other info'
Line3: 'K3455 $100.00'
Line4: 'Last part number here 5551234'
```

What I need is to extract the 3 item numbers, p23344dd5, K3455, and 5551234.

I am using this code, but it just returns if it matches, which is not what i need. I need to return the matched text.

```
import re

items = ['There is some random information here',
         'This includes item p23344dd5 as well as other info',
         'K3455 $100.00',
         'Line4: ''Last part number here 5551234']

for item in items:
    x = re.search(r'^(?=.*\d).{5,}$', item)
    print(x)
```

Comment: `$100.00` is over 4 characters long and contains at least one number. What constitutes a word boundary?

Comment: That is correct, and it looks like it is also returning, so I need to edit my regex to exclude that also.

Comment: If it should be excluded, why? It fits your specification.

Comment: I think that's a good question by @ggorlen. What defines a part number. Is there any other specifications or pattern to pick up here? Or does a part number only allows for digits and alpha chars?

Comment: @JvdV The part number can only contain numbers and letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match the values in the question, you can assert at least 5 word characters from a whitespace boundary, and then match at least a single digit.

```
(?<!\S)(?=\w{5})[^\W\d]*\d\w*(?!\S)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Whitespace boundary at the left
- `(?=\w{5})` Assert 5 word chars
- `[^\W\d]*` Match optional word chars without a digit
- `\d` Match 1 digit
- `\w*` Match optional word chars
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary at the right

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xzMhQP/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/8BZ0F1)

```
import re

items = ['There is some random information here',
         'This includes item p23344dd5 as well as other info',
         'K3455 $100.00',
         'Line4: ''Last part number here 5551234']

for item in items:
    x = re.search(r'(?<!\S)(?=\w{5})\w*\d\w*(?!\S)', item)
    if x:
        print(x.group())

p23344dd5
K3455
5551234
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to extract the matching text. This doesn't fix the issue with the regular expression, as mentioned in the comments, but does extract the matching value as you asked. The problem is that the whole line matches, with the way you have written the regex.

```
import re

items = ['There is some random information here',
         'This includes item p23344dd5 as well as other info',
         'K3455 $100.00',
         'Line4: ''Last part number here 5551234']

for item in items:
    m = re.search(r'^(?=.*\d).{5,}$', item)
    if m is not None:
        print(m.group(0))
```